# Problem with mono when run a windows application

Tags: windows, wine, mono

```
mono myfile.exe
System.DllNotFoundException: wininet.dll
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Multiple_Website_Viewer.Form1:InternetSetOption (intptr,int,intptr,int)
  at Multiple_Website_Viewer.Form1.UseProxy (System.String strProxy) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Multiple_Website_Viewer.Form1:UseProxy (string)
  at Multiple_Website_Viewer.Form1.Button2_Click (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.OnMouseUp (System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs mevent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp (System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs mevent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmLButtonUp (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (IntPtr hWnd, Msg msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

What have I to do? Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Wine and Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: Basically you need to add the missing dll to the wine config.

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is quite self-explanatory: `System.DllNotFoundException: wininet.dll` - you are missing `wininet.dll`, a Windows proprietary item.  So we have to install it.

You could try to do this: `winetricks wininet` - it'll try and install the DLL.  However, this is reported to both work and not work depending on your Wine version.